# Текст стихотворения "Журавли"

Tags: грамматика, литература

Есть стихотворение Р. ГАМЗАТОВА -  "Журавли". Хотелось бы выяснить, как правильно пишется первая фраза в этом стихотворении? Мне попал в руки сборник песен для делегатов XVII Тульской областной комсомольской конференции, где напечатано:

*Мне кажется порою, что солдаты,*

*с кровавых не пришедших полей.*

*Не в землю нашу полезли когда-то,*

*а превратились в белых журавли.*

В слове "пришедших" опечатка или это так должно быть в правильном переводе произведения автора?

Comment: А в другие источники не смотрели?

Comment: Р. ГАМЗАТОВ был переводчиком и знал русский язык прекрасно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> Мне кажется порою, что солдаты,
>   С кровавых **не пришедшие** полей,
>   Не в землю **эту** полегли когда-то,
>   А превратились в белых **журавлей**.

*С кровавых **не пришедшие** полей* — причастный оборот **(согласованный)**.

Comment: Особенно впечатляет источник - *Махачкала, "Дагучпедгиз" 1976.*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova да, какофония чувствуется :)

Comment: В общем, Бернес, Френкель и Гребнев обессмертили песню - Леонид Ильич рыдал, слушаючи... Но совершенно неясно, каково на вкус аварское слово.

Answer (score 1):

"Журавли". Музыкальный шедевр на слова легендарного сына аварского народа Расула Гамзатова. Музыка Яна Френкеля. Перевод Наума Гребнева.

Текст песни на аварском языке (в оригинале)

**Къункъраби**

Дида ккола, рагъда, камурал васал
Кирго рукъун гьечIин, къанабакь лъечIин.
Доба борхалъуда хъахIил зобазда
ХъахIал къункърабазде сверун ратилин.

Гьел иххаз хаселаз халатал саназ
Нилъее салам кьун роржунел руго.
Гьелъин нилъ пашманго, бутIрулги рорхун,
Ралагьулел зодихъ щибаб нухалда.

Боржун унеб буго къункърабазул тIел,
Къукъа буго чIварал гьудулзабазул.
Гьезул тIелалда гъоркь цо бакI бихьула —
Дун вачIине гьаниб къачараб гурищ?

Къо щвела борхатаб хъахIилаб зодихъ
ХъахIаб къункъра лъугьун дунги паркъела.
Гьелъул гьаркьидалъул ракьалда тарал
Киналго нуж, вацал, дица ахIила.

**[источник](http://maarulal.ru/video/muzklip/72-zhuravli-slova-rasula-gamzatova-muzyka-yana.html)**

---

> В 1968 году стихотворение «Журавли» в переводе Наума Гребнева было
>   напечатано в журнале «Новый мир» и начиналось словами:
>
> *Мне кажется порою, что джигиты,*
>
> *С кровавых не пришедшие полей,*
>
> *В могилах братских не были зарыты,*
>
> *А превратились в белых журавлей.*

Московскому **[издательству "Музыка"](http://oleg-pogudin.elegos.ru/forum/18-291-1)** доверять можно.

**ЖУРАВЛИ**

Муз. Я. Френкеля, слова Р. Гамзатова

> *Мне кажется порою, что солдаты,*
>
> *С кровавых не пришедшие полей,*
>
> *Не в землю нашу полегли когда-то,*
>
> *А превратились в белых журавлей.*
>
> ---
>
> *Они до сей поры с времен тех дальних*
>
> *Летят и подают нам голоса.*
>
> *Не потому ль так часто и печально*
>
> *Мы замолкаем, глядя в небеса!*
>
> ---
>
> *Летит, летит по небу клин усталый,*
>
> *Летит в тумане на исходе дня,*
>
> *И в том строю есть промежуток малый,*
>
> *Быть может, это место для меня.*
>
> ---
>
> *Настанет день, и с журавлиной стаей*
>
> *Я поплыву в такой же сизой мгле,*
>
> *Из-под небес по-птичьи окликая*
>
> *Всех вас, кого оставил на земле.*
>
> ---
>
> *Мне кажется порою, что солдаты,*
>
> *С кровавых не пришедшие полей,*
>
> *Не в землю нашу полегли когда-то,*
>
> *А превратились в белых журавлей.*
>
> – Когда я писал это стихотворение, то совсем не думал, что оно когда-нибудь станет песней…
>
> Слова эти принадлежат дагестанскому поэту Расулу Гамзатову, и говорит
>   он о песне, которую без преувеличения можно назвать одной из самых
>   популярных и любимых песен советских людей. Но расскажем обо всем по
>   порядку.
>
> В 1968 году в «Новом мире» были напечатаны стихи Р. Гамзатова в
>   переводе Н. Гребнева. Они начинались словами: «Мне кажется порою, что
>   джигиты, с кровавых не пришедшие полей…»
>
> Стихи назывались «Журавли». На них обратил внимание один из лучших в
>   те годы исполнителей советских песен Марк Бернес.
>
> – Замечательная может получиться песня, – сказал он композитору Яну Френкелю. – Посмотри…
>
> Бернес же попросил поэта внести в стихи некоторые изменения,
>   посоветовал, в частности, заменить слово «джигиты» в первой строке.
>   «Надо, чтобы песня была близка всем, ведь с фашистами сражался весь
>   советский народ».
>
> – Вместе с переводчиком мы сочли пожелания певца справедливыми, – рассказывает Расул Гамзатов, – и вместо «джигиты» написали «солдаты».
>   Это как бы расширило адрес песни, придало ей общечеловеческое
>   звучание.   Окончательный вариант стихов довольно долго лежал у
>   композитора на рояле, он не раз возвращался к ним, но песня все не
>   складывалась. Так продолжалось до тех пор, пока у Френкеля не родилась
>   счастливая мысль: начать песню с вступительного вокализа. А когда этот
>   вокализ был найден, все дальше пошло уже легко, как бы сама собой
>   возникла мелодия «Журавлей».
>
> – Я тут же позвонил Бернесу, – рассказывает народный артист РСФСР, лауреат Государственной премии СССР Ян Френкель. – Он сразу же
>   приехал, послушал песню и… расплакался. Он не был человеком
>   сентиментальным, но нередко случалось, что он плакал, когда ему
>   что-либо нравилось.  Записывал Бернес «Журавли» уже будучи тяжело
>   больным. Это была его последняя запись, его поистине лебединая песня…
>
> «Журавли» нашли свое продолжение в монументальном искусстве. В
>   Чирчике, узбекском городе химиков и металлургов, воздвигнут памятник
>   погибшим героям. На нем изображен журавлиный клин, плывущий в сизой
>   мгле… На основании памятника высечены на узбекском и русском языках
>   знакомые слова:
>
> ***Мне кажется порою, что солдаты,***
>
> ***С кровавых не пришедшие полей,***
>
> ***Не в землю нашу полегли когда-то,***
>
> ***А превратились в белых журавлей.***
>
> Друзья-однополчане: рассказы о песнях, рожденных войной, мелодии и
>   тексты/Авт.-сост. А. Луковников. – Изд. 3-е, доп. – М.: Музыка, 1985.
>   – 252, [4]с. – С.220-221.

Answer (score 0):

В комментарий не помещается...
Тут много говорилось о песне (далеко от вопроса), но перевод стихотворения, который, по слухам, близок оригиналу, от песенного текста сильно отличается. Даю до "кучи", хотя понимаю, что никакой это не ответ, просто к слову.

Мне кажется порою, что джигиты,
С кровавых не пришедшие полей,
В могилах братских не были зарыты,
А превратились в белых журавлей.

Они до сей поры с времен тех дальних
Летят и подают нам голоса.
Не потому ль так часто и печально
Мы замолкаем, глядя в небеса?

Сейчас я вижу: над землей чужою
В тумане предвечернем журавли
Летят своим определенным строем,
Как по земле людьми они брели.

Они летят, свершают путь свой длинный
И выкликают чьи-то имена.
Не потому ли с кличем журавлиным
От века речь аварская сходна?

Летит, летит по небу клин усталый -
Мои друзья былые и родня.
И в их строю есть промежуток малый -
Быть может, это место для меня!

Настанет день, и с журавлиной стаей
Я улечу за тридевять земель,
На языке аварском окликая
Друзей, что были дороги досель.

http://perevod99.blogspot.ru/2011/05/blog-post_9444.html

Последнее четверостишье, имхо, совсем слабое... Но, видимо, это близко к аварскому тексту.

Вот подстрочник

Мне кажется,что погибшие на войне солдаты
Нигде не похоронены,
А высоко в синем небе
превратились в белых журавлей.

Они вёснами, зимами, длинными годами,
Летают, приветствуя нас,
Поэтому мы печально, подняв головы,
Смотрим на небо в каждый раз.

Улетает журавлиная стая,
Группа убитых друзей.
В их стае вижу одно место,
Не подготовленное ли для меня?

Наступит день, на высоком голубом небе
Белым журавлем я промелькну.
Его голосом, оставшихся на земле
Всех вас, братья, я позову.
http://nicolaitroitsky.livejournal.com/4449957.html